# Form creation using factory for fieldset – how to connect the two?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to create a form in Zend Framework 2 utilizing a fieldset created by a factory, but I am having problems to connect the fieldset with the form.

The fieldset is created like this:

```
<?php    
// File: module/FormElements/src/Form/PersonalDataFieldset.php

namespace FormElements\Form;

use Zend\Form\Factory;

class PersonalDataFieldset extends Factory
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $factory = new Factory();
        $form = $factory->createForm(array(
            'fieldsets' => array(
                array(
                    'spec' => array(
                        'name' => 'data',
                        'options' => array(
                            'label' => 'Fieldset Test',
                        ),
                        'elements' => array(
                            array(
                                'spec' => array(
                                    'name' => 'fname',
                                    'type' => 'text',
                                ),
                            ),
                            array(
                                'spec' => array(
                                    'name' => 'lname',
                                    'type' => 'text',
                                ),
                            ),
                            array(
                                'spec' => array(
                                    'name' => 'email',
                                    'type' => 'email',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

The form:

```
<?php
// File: module/FormElements/src/Form/PersonalDataForm.php

namespace FormElements\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class PersonalDataForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Field not contained in the fieldset - this works
        $this->add(array(
            'name'=> 'some-name',
            'type' => 'text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Test Label',
            ),
        ));

        // Here I am trying to add the fieldset – this does not work
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'some-other-name',
            'type' => 'FormElements\Form\PersonalDataFieldset',
        ));
    }
}
```

And the controller that should connect the two:

```
<?php
// File: module/FormElements/src/Controller/FormElementsController.php

namespace FormElements\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use FormElements\Form\PersonalDataForm;

class FormElementsController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $form = new PersonalDataForm();

        return new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $form
        ));
    }
}
```

Depending on what I try, the results vary between an empty view or exceptions.

For example, with the code posted above, I get `Plugin of type FormElements\Form\PersonalDataFieldset is invalid; must implement Zend\Form\ElementInterface`.
Of course I could implement the Interface because the exceptions tells me to do so, but I would like to understand what I am doing, but I don't know why this interface should be required?

- Where am I going wrong – why does the way I try it does not work?
- When creating a Fieldset, the the factory's method `createForm` is used, but there is also `createFieldset`– what is the correct method? Also, why is there no need to extend `Zend\Form\Fieldset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid calling `$form = new PersonalDataForm();` in your controller.

I would inject that dependency in a factory, that factory should have access to the "FormElementManager"

FormElementManager is a AbstractPluginManager where one can store all their form related services, including Elements, Fieldsets and full Forms (as they all extend Zend\Form\Element)

By calling your form services from the plugin manager (and making sure to inject that plugin manager into any subsequent form factories), you won't run into these "Invalid Plugin" errors.

The "Invalid Plugin" exception usually means one of two things. You didn't register your element with the plugin manager, or you didn't properly inject the plugin manager where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Move your fields and fieldsets add methods from `__construct()` to the `init()` method and grab your form with the FormElementManager. It works the Same Way Custom Elements work as described here [zf2 docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#creating-custom-elements)

Edit 1: i fixed the link, seems that the # symbol waned encoded correctly

Edit 2: here is a quote of the part from the ZF2 Docs:

> *...Example code for custom element...*
>
> And now comes the first catch.
>
> If you are creating your form class by extending Zend\Form\Form, you must not add the custom element in the __construct-or (as we have done in the previous example where we used the custom element’s FQCN), but rather in the init() method:

```
namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class MyForm extends Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'phone',
            'type' => 'Phone',
        ));
    }
 }
```

> The second catch is that you must not directly instantiate your form class, but rather get an instance of it through the Zend\Form\FormElementManager:

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $form = $sl->get('FormElementManager')->get('\Application\Form\MyForm');
        return array('form' => $form);
    }
}
```

> The biggest gain of this is that you can easily override any built-in Zend Framework form elements if they do not fit your needs. For instance, if you want to create your own Email element instead of the standard one, you can simply create your element and add it to the form element config with the same key as the element you want to replace
>   ...

Comment: It that so often mentioned case when the link is broken and post does not have enough info.

Comment: @vlr i've extended my answer, hope its more helpful now